# (Text) right overflowed by 205 pixels

Tags: flutter, material-ui, flutter-layout, flutter-cupertino

```
ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
                        child: Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            height: 100,
                            color: Colors.grey[100],
                            child: Row(// this
                                children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    20, 10, 5, 10),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: const [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "1",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 35,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "MAY",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 17,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Color.fromARGB(
                                              255, 231, 95, 97)),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 5),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Viral fever & Cough",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 17,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Two dolo 650 one to be taken in the morning, another in the evening",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey[600]),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                        20, 0, 20, 10),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Dr. Shetty",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Color.fromARGB(
                                            255, 63, 134, 172),
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            ]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
```

I was trying to fit the text into a container, but it didn't work out. I wanted it to go ... at the end of the container What should I edit or add to fit the text in the container? Can you help me out?
[ Also, I am sorry this question might have been asked many times on StackOverflow. ]

**Current:**
[image]

**Expected:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `Expanded` wrapping the `Column` that contains the `Text`.

In the source code of your question, that would be 10 lines down from the word "MAY", that `Column`, wrap an `Expanded` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this website:

https://kindacode.com/article/text-overflow-in-flutter

It has the answer to your question!

Comment: np have fun coding!

Answer (score 1):

you have to make it flexible size,

for your `Column` or `Row` you may use `Expanded`.
here some example if you want to  try it

similar question: [Overflow within a Column when mapping out items, Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73469508/12838877)

Demo :
https://dartpad.dev/?id=7787182fed870e512474ef4779de2271

[image]